# How to eliminate error underlining in IntelliJ 14.0.3 for Play 2.3.7 application?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework-2.3, intellij-14

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.3 to develop a Play 2.3.7 application using the Scala 1.3.3 plugin.

The attached screenshot shows that IntelliJ underlines the parameter to a render method as invalid when, in fact, the system compiles and runs successfully both in IntelliJ and at the command line (using Activator):

[image: play-intellij-confusion]

Another user has reported this problem in IntelliJ when the view template file uses Scala-specific syntax (i.e. `Form[formdata.ContactFormData]`) while the controller uses Java-specific syntax (i.e. `Form<formdata.ContactFormdata>`). That is the case here as well.

The sources to illustrate this problem are available at: https://github.com/philipmjohnson/intellij-play-error-highlight-problem

Is this indeed a bug in IntelliJ or its Scala plugin? Are there any workarounds?

Comment: Have you logged a bug / looked for an existing one in the [YouTrack JetBrains issue tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  Now posted to JetBrains as: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-136991

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My team and I have this same issue, using Intellij 14.0.3, Scala 1.3.3 plugin and Play 2.3.8.

To workaround this I open File --> Project Structure, then click on "Modules" on the left side bar.  Adding `target/scala-2.11/src_managed/main` to the sources eliminates these reverse routing underlines.  Make sure that the root `target` directory is not in the excluded folders.

One thing to note however, is that Intellij seems to remove this from the sources from time to time, causing much annoyance...

[image: Intellij 14 Modules]

Comment: Fantastic!  So others can get there faster: be sure to add both the twirl and src_managed main directories (exactly as shown in the accompanying image).  Once I set up mine to look just like Jarrett's, the red lines disappeared.

Comment: After further experience, I am finding that IntelliJ does not always eliminate the red underline after a successful rebuild of a Play project.  In this case (so far), if I close and re-open the project, the red underline goes away.

Comment: I have noticed that from time to time Intellij removes that as a source, making me re-add it.  Sometimes it's after a restart, sometimes just while working and compiling.  This is extremely irritating, so if you, or someone else, figures out how to fix that, that'd be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

The above solution works, but I think it might be useful to document a ripple effect: if you are using the Checkstyle plugin, then after adding those additional source root directories, Checkstyle will process those auto-generated Java files and (in all likelihood) raise a number of (spurious) warnings.

After fiddling around a bit, it appears the easiest way to get Checkstyle to skip those files is to specify the "Inspection Scope" as the "Default" version control scope.  Since you will almost certainly exclude the target/ directory from version control, this parameter to Checkstyle keeps it on the straight and narrow.  Here's a screen image illustrating the setting:

[image]